Does $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = f(x) \implies \limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n = x$ if f is strictly increasing?
Hi I was working on the following question : 
Given a real series $(a_n)_n$ ,$x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ a strictly increasing function. 
Does $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = f(x) $
imply :
$\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n = x$ ? 
I tried prooving this by taking $A_n = \{a_m \: | m\ge n \}$ with n a random natural number. As $A_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ has a countable number of elements $\sup{A_n}$ is well defined. I then define $F_n = \{f(a_m) \: | m\ge n \}$, not that $\sup{F_n}$ is well defined as well. I now want to proof that $\sup{F_n} = f(\sup{A_n})$. Assume $\sup{F_n} < f(\sup{A_n})$. I assumed I could proof this but then came up with which what I think is a counter example : take $f(x) = x $ if $x <2$ and $f(x) = x+1 $ if $x \geq 2$. This function is strictly increasing. Take $a_n = 2 - \frac{1}{n}$ then $\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n = 2$ thus $x=2$, $f(x) = 3$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = 2 \neq 3$ is my counter example correct or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance, jip

You want $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(x)\Rightarrow\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}a_n=x$. Your counterexample shows $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}a_n=x\Rightarrow\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(x)$ is false.

@Lucenaposition ow thx! that's whats wrong.

'As $A_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ has a countable number of elements $\sup{A_n}$ is well defined':  very strange statement.

The reals have the least upper bound property. This means any non-empty set of reals with an upper bond has a least upper bound.

For all $\epsilon > 0$ is
$$
 \limsup_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = f(x) \,
\begin{cases}
 < f(x + \epsilon) \\ > f(x - \epsilon)
\end{cases}
$$
so that
$$
\begin{align}
 f(a_n) < f(x + \epsilon) \quad &\text{for all sufficiently large $n$, and} \\
 f(a_n) > f(x - \epsilon) \quad &\text{for infinitely many $n$.} 
\end{align}
$$
It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
 a_n < x + \epsilon \quad &\text{for all sufficiently large $n$, and} \\
 a_n > x - \epsilon \quad &\text{for infinitely many $n$,} 
\end{align}
$$
and therefore
$$
 x - \epsilon \le \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n \le x + \epsilon \, .
$$
This holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, so that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n = x$.

The reverse implication
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n = x \implies \limsup_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = f(x)
$$
does not hold in general, and that is what your example demonstrates.
